# Concatenating variable into a regex php

Tags: php, regex

I have these arrays (array and array2)

```
$urls = array("http://piggington.com/pb_cash_flow_positive")
```

I have this regular expression

```
(preg_match("/\/{2}.*?\./", $array[$i], $matches))
```

It checks for everything that comes after 2nd slash and before 1st dot. So it will find

```
/piggington.
```

Now want to concatenate a variable inside the following regular expression, so it will search for a specific string.

I tried:

```
$matches_imploded = implode($matches);
$matches_imploded = preg_quote($matches_imploded, '/');
$match_with_other_array = preg_grep("/\/{2}".$matches_imploded."\./", $array2);
```

But it's not finding any matches.. What am I doing wrong? It should be looking inside array2 and making a positive match with $matches_imploded

```
between second slash and first dot we found $matches_imploded
```

Comment: note that your regex would match `//piggington` not `/piggington`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match everything which comes after `//` and before the first dot, you need to use `\K` or positive lookbehind.

```
preg_match("~/{2}\K[^.]*(?=.)~", $array[$i], $matches)
$matches_imploded = implode($matches);
$matches_imploded = preg_quote($matches_imploded, '/');
$match_with_other_array = preg_grep("/\/{2}".$matches_imploded."\./", $array2);
```

Comment: ok, thank you and "preg_grep("/\/{2}".$matches_imploded."\./", $array2);" would be the proper way to concatenate it?